# Iterating through a boolean value in a dictionary issue

Tags: python, dictionary, compression

I have a code like this:

```
def myfun(*args):
    return {i: sum(k % i == 0 for k in args) for i in range(1,10)}

myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20)
{1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0}
```

And I want to convert it to a function without a dict comprehension:

```
def myfun(*args):
    for item in args:
        for item_2 in range(1,10):
            return {item_2:sum(item % item_2 == 0)}

myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20)
```

But I get:

```
----> 4             return {item_2:sum(item % item_2 == 0)}
      5 
      6 myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20)

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

What exactly is the bool value that is returned rather than the sum?

Comment: The bool is the argument to `sum`. `sum` requires an iterable argument.

Answer (score 1):

To unwrap the nested dict comprehension, you would end up with two `for` loops. First you'd iterate over your `range` and initialize a dict entry (your sum value) to `0`. Then you'd loop over your `args` and do your mod check, and increment the value if necessary. This will emulate your `sum` expression.

```
def myfun(*args):
    result = {}
    for i in range(1,10):
        result[i] = 0
        for k in args:
            if k % i == 0:
                result[i] += 1
    return result

>>> myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20)
{1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct non dict comprehension syntax:

```
def myfun(*args):
    result = {}
    for i in range(1,10):
        result[i] = sum(k % i == 0 for k in args)
    return result

print(myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20))
```

Output:

```
{1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0}
```